# oracle installation pre requisite check error

Tags: centos-7, oracle-11g

I'm trying to install Oracle 11gR2 on Oracle Linux 7.4.

While the installer is performing prerequisite checks, we are  getting error:

This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the OS kernel parameter "semmni" is properly set. (more details)

Expected Value : 128

Actual Value : 0

Comment: This was really, really easy to find an answer to: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cwlin/changing-kernel-parameter-values.html#GUID-FB0CC366-61C9-4AA2-9BE7-233EB6810A31